# Как учитывая предыдущие значения посчитать прогноз?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть DataFrame:

```
Data  Interval prognoz
3414  A2       3289
3563  A3       3289
3391  A2       3289
3463  A2       3289
3110  A1       3289
2844  A1       3289
3292  A2       3289
3321  A2       3289
3608  A3       3289
2753  A1       3289
2886  A1       3289
3596  A3       3289
3644  A3       3289
4029  A4       3814
4023  A4       3814
4870  A6       4026
5859  A8       5618
6321  A9       5674
5923  A8       5618
5699  A8       5618
5521  A7       5827
5995  A9       5674
```

Я считаю прогноз по каждому интервалу, например, в первой строке у меня интервал А2 значит и считаю по А2, но нужно наоборот. Если в первой строке интервал А2, то мы по этому интервалу считаем прогноз для второй строки и так далее,по интервалу второй строки считаем прогноз для третьей строки.

```
f = []
for i, _ in enumerate(df["Data"]):  # по факту просто цикл от 0 до 21
    A = (df.iloc[i, 1])  # нахожу к какой А отнесли эту строку

    words = (res['Groups'][A])  # нахожу в какую группу входит данные с найденной строки
    summa = 0  # сюда прогноз суммирую
    # print(A, 11111111111, words)
    pari = grupb(str.split(words))
    par = (res['pari'][A])
    for j in pari:  # цикл по всем А из группы

        summa += res['sred'][j]
        # print(res['sred'][j], j)
        prog = summa / par
    f.append(prog)
    # print(prog)
```

Kак исправить этот код?

На выходе:

```
Data  Interval prognoz
3414  A2       
3563  A3       3289
3391  A2       3289
3463  A2       3289
3110  A1       3289
2844  A1       3289
3292  A2       3289
3321  A2       3289
3608  A3       3289
2753  A1       3289
2886  A1       3289
3596  A3       3289
3644  A3       3289
4029  A4       3289
4023  A4       3814 
4870  A6       3814 
5859  A8       4026
6321  A9       5618
5923  A8       5674
5699  A8       5618
5521  A7       5618
5995  A9       5827
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [Series.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
s = pd.Series(f)
df["prognoz"] = s.shift(-1)
```

Comment: Это поставит в конце цикла?

Comment: @КириллАщепов, после цикла